# Simple loop program that won't terminate on command

Tags: c, loops

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main() {


    char name[32];
    int grade1;
    int grade2;
    int grade3;
    int grade4;
    char end[32]="unknown";

    begin:
    printf("Welcome to the student Quiz Calculator Program.\n");
    printf("Enter a Student Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name[32]);

    if(name == end){
    goto terminate;
    }
    else {
    printf("Enter quiz grade 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 4: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade4);
    printf("Average Quiz Calculation for %s with grades of %d, %d, %d, and %d is %d.\n", name, grade1,    grade2, grade3, grade4, grade1+grade2+grade3+grade>

    goto begin;
    }

    terminate:
    printf("have a nice day");
    return 0;
    }
```

So I need this program to repeat its self continuously asking the user the name of the student, the grades and then outputting the average. When the user enters the name "Unknown", the program should give a good bye banner then terminate. When I run this, it doesn't recognize any names i put into it and it continuously repeats itself even when you input "Unknown", not sure how to straighten this out. I appreciate the help.

I messed with it a little using the goto/terminate/begin. but nothing seems to change the output.

Comment: To compare strings, use strcmp and its family. You are comparing pointers.

Comment: `do { ... } while()` structure fit more in this case. Also "Unknown" and "unknown" different.

Comment: I tried the do...while statement, but I am still getting the same output. I cant get it to terminate when you input unknown.

Comment: You have tagged this question as C++, but this looks like C to me.  If you are truly using C++, it would be much easier to use things like `std::string` instead of `char[32]`.

Comment: @0x5453 C has loops. I think it is something before FORTRAN.

Comment: Oh yes, this is C. I'll change that now. thanks for the heads up